# Check who created android app via email/password combination

Tags: android

Is it possible to *ask* google who created a certain android app? For example, can I check if *email* and *password* was the creator of *com.android.app* via the information stored in google play store by requesting it to google? If so, how?

Comment: No this is not possible

Comment: But is it possible to do the check if the user is already logged in the device by google play store?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the developer email address from google play store App detail page